# Google Drive API list method is recursive?

Tags: python, google-drive-api

juste a simple question for professional use. Can you tell me if the list method with drive API v2 is recursive? If it search for real all the files existing in a GDrive account?

My code for example (Python):

```
def getUserFiles(service, parent):
try:
    results = []
    page_token = None
    while True:
        param = {}
        if page_token:
            param['pageToken'] = page_token
        param['q'] = '"me" in owners'
        if parent:
            param['q'] += " and '%s' in parents" % parent
        param['maxResults'] = 500
        param['fields'] = 'nextPageToken, items(id, mimeType)'
        files = service.files().list(**param).execute()
        results.extend(files['items'])
        page_token = files.get('nextPageToken')
        if not page_token:
            break
    return results
except Exception as e:
    logging.error('Error getting user\'s files : %s' % e)
```

I add this too :

```
files = getUserFiles(driveService, args.parent)
logging.info('Get childrens for each folders')
for f in files:
    if f['mimeType'] == 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder':
        files.extend(getUserFiles(driveService, f['id']))
```

But i want to know if it's useless if the list method return all files...

Thank you! (sorry for my bad english)

Answer (score 0):

Don't exactly get your point 'recursive' but Files.list in Drive API should return all the files. Also, I'd like to recommend you use the [Files.list v3](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/permissions/create).

If you want to list the folders only, use [queries](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/search-parameters#examples) like:

```
results = service.files().list(
        q="mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder'"
        pageSize=10,
        fields="nextPageToken,
         files(id, name)")
         .execute()
    items = results.get('files', [])
```

That code was from [Python Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/quickstart/python).

Comment: What i want to know it's if the Files.list method will list ALL files/folders in a given Drive

Comment: yes it does, provided it's your drive hence the term "list"

Comment: Ok thank you, because i have a doubt about that and it was the reason with a add the foreach after

Comment: Check the [Python Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/quickstart/python) whos main sample is listing files (but set to 10 items per request).

Comment: Hum you talk about the v3 but i currently use the v2. Do you think the v2 is recursive too?

Comment: no such thing. i just prefer using the latest. there's a v2 version also.